# Uploaded extension package is missing an 'overview.md' file which is a mandatory details asset

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

While trying to publish an extension to the marketplace I bumped into this error message.

```
The supplied extension definition isn't valid: 
'Uploaded extension package is missing an 'overview.md' file which is a mandatory details asset. 
Try again after adding the file.'
```

Yet, my extension has the mandatory `details` asset in the `vss-extension.json`:

```json
content": {
  "details": {
    "path": "overview.md"
  }
}
```

And the file is present in the generated vsix:

[image: screenshot of vsix file contents containing overview.md]

Comment: See also: https://github.com/microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you try to simply include everything in the extension with:

```json
"files": [
  {
    "path": "."
  }
]
```

It overrides the metadata for the "special content files" when these files are matched by the listed files.

So, I ended up moving all the build task in the extension to a `_tasks` folder and instead of  lazily including everything, I'm now lazily including `_tasks`:

```json
"files": [
  {
    "path": "_tasks"
  }
],
```

With this change, the vsix has the required metadata on the `overview.md`:

`vsix\extension.vsixmanifest`

```xml
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default" d:Source="File" Path="icon-default.png" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Large" d:Source="File" Path="icon-large.png" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Details" d:Source="File" Path="overview.md" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.License" d:Source="File" Path="LICENSE" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Privacy" d:Source="File" Path="PRIVACY.md" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Manifest" d:Source="File" Path="extension.vsomanifest" Addressable="true"/>
  </Assets>
```